# Improve database and SQL request

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables:

Products (id, name, description, price, categoryname, categorydescription)

Orderitems (id, date, productid, userid)

User (id, createdat, email)

I want to:

1. improve this database
2. a request that returns the number of products sold by category and the turnover by category.

In subscribe.php:

```
<?php
class SubscribeController
{
public function postEmailAction(){
return mysqlquery('INSERT INTO emails (createdat, email) VALUES(NOW(), "'.$_POST{'email' }.'"));
}
}
```

3. I want to send a POST request with the same way to change in the database the name of product id:1 et delete product id:2.
4. How to secure this controller

Answer (score 0):

"Cette personne %s veux vous ajouter à sa liste d'amis" in your xml
then assuming `notification.getTarget()` is the xml string use `String.format(notification.getTarget(), noun)`